# posgresql upsert

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Как вернуть строку при конфликтной вставке?

```
        async with self.db.acquire() as conn:
            values = {
                'phone': phone,
                'parent': parent,
                'username': '%s@%s' % (phone, parent)
                }
            query = insert(db.user).values(
                    **values
                ).on_conflict_do_nothing(
                    constraint='unique_parent_phone'
                ).returning(
                    *[sa.column(i) for i in values.keys()]
                )
            ret = await conn.execute(query)
```

При первой вставке я получаю добавленную строчку. Если такая строчка уже есть - не получаю ничего в ответ.

Comment: А метод `on_conflict_do_nothing` (на конфликт ничего не делать) в запросе что делает?

Comment: @microcoder не дает перевызвать исключение питоне